# Html radio buttons in a shiny APP

Tags: html, r, shiny

Since yesterday I run a shiny app with radiobuttons in a HTML table. I used a code like this:

ui.r

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Download Example'),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(              
    fluidRow( 
       HTML('<div class="attr-col">
               <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="var" id="var1" value="A" checked="checked"/>
                    Option 1
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="var" id="var2" value="B" />
                      Option 2
                    </li>
               </ul>
            </div>'
       )
    ),  
    fluidRow(                         
      verbatimTextOutput("sel")  
    )
  )
))
```

server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$sel<-renderText ({ input$var })
})
```

The code above works good in R 3.0.2 and shiny 0.11.1 ! But with R 3.2.0 and shiny 0.12.0 it doesn't.
I need to keep the HTML because I use a CSS to format a big table with other objects. I don't understand why in the new version the input$var can't reach the server. It is changed something in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about that. Can you try changing the outer div to `<div class="attr-col shiny-input-radiogroup" id="var">`?